# AWS code deploy to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, wildfly, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

Right now I am manually deploying WAR files onto wildfly server(which is hosted on an ec2 instance) but I want to automate this and get rid of the manual deployments.

I build the application using jenkins (from another EC2 instance) and after that i want to deploy to the wildfly server and since i am also planning to user codepipeline, can anyone please tell me how to deploy an applcation on wildfly server using AWS CodeDeploy?

I am new to codedeploy so not that familiar with its usage.

Thank you,
Ajit

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ajith Code Deploy is the perfect tool for deploying applications in AWS. But it has some limitations, for example to give a source repository for the Code Build/ Code Deploy you can only choose these 3 as the code repository.

1. AWS Code Commit
2. AWS S3 Bucket
3. Guthub

You cant provide your own custom repository or Bitbucket. Please go through the below Examples for deploying applications using Code Deploy. I can't explain all the steps because it have a lot of steps. here they are explaining app deployment using tomcat, replace this with your wildfly scripts.

[Deploy Applications From S3 using Code Deploy.](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-deploy-application-code-from-s3-using-aws-codedeploy/)